# GITLens switch to commit made my newer commits disappear

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlens

very scary situation right now: I have used the `GitLens` extension of `VSCode` to jump back to an older commit. I wanted to `checkout` the commit, located it in the `COMMITS` sidebar, right clicked and selected `Switch to Commit...`. I did expect to checkout to that commit, and then be able to check out back to my current state.

Now running `git log`shows me the log of my commits only up to the point of the commit that I have selected. This is scary. Where are my newer commits?

As it is now I cannot locate my newer commits and go back to them. I have made a new commit just before switching to the older commit, so I am 100% certain there should be newer commits.
This is a new project that I have not committed to any remote location yet, so `git pull`cannot bail me out.

I really hope someone can help me, I do not want to loose 2 days of work...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This *is* scary, to those new to Git.  But don't worry: all the commits are still there.

Various GUIs, including Visual Studio, block access to Git (which could be good or bad, depending on your point of view) so that you can't see what's really going on, and I don't *use* these GUIs, because they keep you from seeing what's going on, so I can't say what, precisely, each clicky button in your GUI does.  *Git*, however, works like this:

- There is, at all times,<sup>1</sup> a *current commit*.  Git has a special name for this commit: `HEAD`, written in all uppercase just like this.<sup>2</sup>
- At *most* times, there is also a *current branch*.  Git has a special name by which you can access this current branch: `HEAD`.

You might—in fact, you should—object at this point: how do we know whether `HEAD` refers to the *commit* or to the *branch name?*  Git's answer is: *I pick one or the other based on whichever one I want at the moment.*  Some things *need* a branch name, in which case, `HEAD` turns into the branch name.  Some things *need* a *commit*, in which case `HEAD` turns into the commit.  Basically there are two internal ways Git has to ask *what's the HEAD now*.  One gives a branch-name answer, like `master` or `main` or whatever, and the other gives you a raw commit hash ID.

OK, so, with this in mind, we now remember that `git log` prints out the log like this:

```
commit eb27b338a3e71c7c4079fbac8aeae3f8fbb5c687 (...)
Author: ...
   ...

commit fe3fec53a63a1c186452f61b0e55ac2837bf18a1
...
```

That is, we see all these weird hash IDs spill out, one at a time.  The hash IDs are the actual, true-names of each commit.  Each commit gets a globally-unique hash ID: no two *different* commits are *ever* allowed to have the same one.  That's why the hash IDs are so big and ugly.  They *look* random.  They aren't actually random, but they *are* unpredictable.<sup>3</sup>

A *branch name* like `main` translates to a commit hash ID.  A raw hash ID already *is* a hash ID.  Either way, given the right hash ID, Git can find the commit.

Each commit holds a full snapshot of every file,<sup>4</sup> plus some *metadata:* information about the commit itself, such as who made it, and when, and a log message they can write at the time.  Crucially for Git itself, one item in this metadata is the *raw hash ID of the previous commit*.

There's one other random fact about commits that is useful to remember here: Once made, no part of *any* commit can ever be *changed*.  That's how the hash IDs actually work, and it's critical to Git being a *distributed* version control system.  But it also means that no Git commit can ever contain the raw hash ID of its future *children* commits, because we have no idea what those will be when we create the commit.  Commits *can* store the "names" (hash IDs) of their parents, because we *do* know their ancestry when we create the children.

What this means for us here is that the *commits* remember their *parents*, which forms a sort of backwards-looking chain.  All we have to do is remember the raw hash ID of the *latest* commit.  When we do that, we end up with a chain that we can draw like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--main
```

Here, the *name* `main` holds the real hash ID of the *latest commit*, which for drawing purposes, we just call `H`.  Commit `H` in turn holds the hash ID of earlier commit `G`, which holds the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`, and so on.

We can now see how `git log` works: it starts with the *current commit*, `H`, as selected by the *current branch*, `main`.  To make `main` *be* the current branch, we *attach* the special name `HEAD` to the name `main`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

Git uses `HEAD` to find `main`, uses `main` to find `H`, and shows us `H`.  Then Git uses `H` to find `G` and shows us `G`; then it uses `G` to find `F`, and so on.

When we want to look at any *historical* commit, we pick it out, by hash ID, and tell Git: *attach `HEAD` directly to that commit*.  We can draw that like this:

```
...--F   <-- HEAD
      \
       G--H   <-- main
```

When we run `git log` now, Git translates `HEAD` to a hash ID—which it finds directly this time; there's no attached *branch name*—and shows us commit `F`.  Then `git log` moves on from there, *backwards*.  Where are commits `G` and `H`?  They are nowhere to be seen!

But it's OK: if we run `git log main`, `git log` starts with the name `main`, rather than with the name `HEAD`.  That finds commit `H`, which `git log` shows; then `git log` moves to `G`, and so on.  Or, we can even run:

```
git log --branches
```

or:

```
git log --all
```

to have `git log` find *all branches* or *all refs* ("refs" include branches and tags, but also other kinds of names).

(This brings up another, separate can-of-worms, which is all about how `git log` handles the case of "wanting" to show more than one commit "at the same time".  I won't go there at all, in this answer.)

This "viewing a historical commit" mode, in Git, is called **detached HEAD mode**.  That's because the special name `HEAD` is no longer *attached to* a branch name.  To *re-attach* your `HEAD`, you simply choose a branch name, with `git checkout` or (Git 2.23 or later) `git switch`:

```
git switch main
```

for instance.  You've now checked out the commit that the branch name `main` selects, and `HEAD` is now re-attached to the name `main`.

Before we stop, there's one more really important thing to learn, which is: *how branches grow*.  But let me get footnotes out of the way first.

---

<sup>1</sup>There's an exception to this rule, necessary in a new, totally empty repository that has no commits at all.  That exception can be used in a weird way later, in a non-empty repository.  You won't be making use of this though.

<sup>2</sup>The lowercase variant, `head`, often "works" on Windows and macOS (but not on Linux and others).  However, this is deceptive, because if you start using the `git worktree` feature, `head` (lowercase) *doesn't* work correctly—it gets you the wrong commit sometimes!—while `HEAD` (uppercase) does.  If you don't like typing in all-caps, consider using the shorthand `@` character, which you can use instead of `HEAD`.

<sup>3</sup>Git uses cryptographic hashing here: the same kind of stuff one finds in cryptocurrencies, though not as strict (Git currently still uses SHA-1, which is already outdated in cryptographic terms).

<sup>4</sup>The snapshots are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format.  Git *shows* commits as "changes since previous commit" but *stores* commits as snapshots.

---

#### How Git branches grow

Suppose we have the following situation:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

We now want to make a *new commit*, but we'd like to put it on a *new branch*.  So we first as Git to make a new branch name, and point that name to commit `H` too:

```
git branch develop
```

which results in:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

Now we pick `develop` as the name to have `HEAD` attached-to, with `git checkout` or `git switch`:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

Note that we're still using *commit* `H`.  We're just using it through the other *name* now.  The commits up through and including `H` are *on both branches*.

We now make a new commit, the usual way we do in Git.  Once we're ready, we run `git commit` and give Git a log message to put in the *metadata* for the new commit.  Git now:

- saves a snapshot of every file (de-duplicated as usual);
- uses the *current commit* as the *parent* for the new commit, so that our new commit—which we'll call `I`—will point backwards to existing commit `H`;
- adds our configured `user.name` and `user.email` as the author and committer of this new commit, using "now" as the date-and-time;
- uses our log message; and
- actually writes all of this out as a commit, which assigns it its unique hash ID.  (The uniqueness comes in part from the date-and-time stamp, and in part from the input hash ID `H`, and in part from the snapshot we've saved: *everything* that is in the new commit goes into making up the new random-looking hash ID, which is why we can't predict it.)

So now we have this new commit `I`, pointing back to existing commit `H`:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

Now Git does the other bit of magic that makes it all work: *`git commit` writes `I`'s hash ID into the current branch name*.  That is, Git uses `HEAD` to find the *name* of the current branch, and *updates the hash ID* stored in that branch name.  So our picture is now:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

The name `HEAD` is still attached to the branch name `develop`, but the branch name `develop` now selects commit `I`, not commit `H`.

It's commit `I` that leads back to commit `H`.  The *name* just lets us find the *commit*.  The *commits* are what really matter: branch names are just there to let us find the *last* commit.  Whatever hash ID is in that branch name, Git says that *that* commit *is* the *last* commit on that branch.  So since `main` says `H` right now, `H` is the *last* commit on `main`; since `develop` says `I` right now, `I` is the *last* commit on `develop`.  Commits up through `H` are *still on both branches*, but `I` is only on `develop`.

Later, if we like, we can have Git *move the name `main`*.  Once we move `main` to `I`:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- develop, main
```

then all commits are once again on both branches.  (I left out `HEAD` this time because we might not care which branch we are "on", if both select `I`.  In fact, we can delete either name—but not both—because *both names select the same commit* and that's all we *need* to find the right hash ID.  If we were to write this hash ID down somewhere, we might not need *any* name.  But that would be ... yucky, at best.  We have a *computer;* let's have *it* save the big ugly hash IDs for us, in nice neat names.)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this in depth explanation! Now I see, as I had moved my HEAD down the commit tree, I did not see any my newer commits. Did not know it worked that way. `git log --all` helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, getting over my initial panic helped me to find this solution:

The `reflog` of git stores all information on changes done in git.

Runnin `git reflog` gave me this line:

`e7aaac3 HEAD@{3}: commit: Some Commit...`

With this I could
`git checkout HEAD@{3}`
which brought me to my newest commit (but I had moved the `HEAD` before trying to retrieve the commit).
Now to cleanly get back the HEAD to this commit without using the `reset` command I did create a new branch, and then merged the branch back to main.